# File handling and functions(Updating a file)

Tags: c, turbo-c++

Now the functions are working the file. Updated the file successfully. but when I print `x.curbal`
for example `printf("Current Balance: %.2f\n",x.curbal);` it prints the **old** value. But when I close the program and open it again the **new** value has been printed.

```
void updateFile(struct client x, float bal)
{
    FILE *orig;
    FILE *copy;



    orig = fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","r");

    fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,orig);
    /*fscanf(orig,"%s %s %s %s %f",x.accnum,x.accode,x.fname,x.lname,x.curbal);*/
    x.curbal = bal;
    copy = fopen("temp.txt","w");

    fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,copy);
    /*fprintf(copy,"%s %s %s %s %f",x.accnum,x.accode,x.fname,x.lname,x.curbal);*/

    fclose(orig);
    fclose(copy);

    remove("account.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","account.txt");

}

void withdraw(struct client x)
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *orig;
    FILE *copy;
    float debit = 0;
    float withdrawal;

    fp = fopen("history.txt","a+");
    if (fp!=NULL)
    {   
        printf("====WITHDRAW====\n");
        printf("Date: %s\n",currdate);
        printf("Time: %s\n",currtime);
        printf("Name: %s,%s\n",x.lname,x.fname);
        printf("Account Number: %s\n",x.accnum);
        printf("Current Balance: %.2f\n",x.curbal);
        printf("Withdrawal Amount: Php ");
        scanf("%f",&withdrawal);

        if((s.curbal-withdrawal) < 0)
        {
            clrscr();
            system("cls");  
            printf("Transaction Failed.\n\n");  
            printf("Insufficient Funds!!!\n\n");    
            getch();

        }

        else
        {

            x.curbal = x.curbal - withdrawal;
            clrscr();
            updateFile(x,x.curbal);
            fprintf(fp,"%s %s %s %.2f %.2f\n",x.accnum,histdate,currtime,debit,withdrawal);
            printf("Transaction Completed.\n\n");
            printf("Php %.2f was deducted.\n\n",withdrawal);
            printf("Remaining Balance: Php %.2f\n\n\n",x.curbal);

            getch();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Before anything else, check *all* of your IO operations for success rather than assuming they worked.

Comment: this line: 'void updateFile(struct client x, float bal)' should be: 'void updateFile(struct client* x, float bal)'  then this line: 'fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,orig);' should be: 'fread(&x,sizeof(struct client),1,orig);' and this line: 'fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,copy);' should be: 'fwrite(&x,sizeof(struct client),1,copy);'  because C passes parameters by value, not by reference, so the callers' data is not updated with the current code

Comment: Yes, they are working.

Comment: this line: 'orig = fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","a+");' will (at the fread) try to read past the end of the file.  suggest using: 'orig = fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","r");'

Comment: I don't use "a+" with fopen often, but doesn't it open the file for append?  Reading when your file pointer is at the end of the file probably isn't working.  Assuring us the calls work is not convincing, proper checking of return values for errors is.

Comment: actually it is "r" and "w". I changed it to "a+" maybe it will work. But it is still not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain the actual code you're having a problem with.

Comment: yes sorry about that. I was trying other ways.

Comment: Changed it to "r" and "w". Now it is working. But how come I when I print x.curbal the value is the original value not the updated value.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer below you are passing a copy of the struct to your functions, so if you're hoping the values will be updated outside the functions you're out of luck.  You should also consider opening the file in binary mode since you are reading/writing binary data to it.

Comment: the function withdraw() contains a reference to a variable 's', but 's' is not defined.  It would have been much simpler to debug if the code included the definition of the struct client.  I made some assumptions about the contents of struct client in my answers  There were numerous compiler warnings and errors output with the original code.  suggest posting code that compiles cleanly (no warnings/errors) in the future.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks for noticing the need for 'binary' mode, I missed that detail

Comment: `fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","r"); ... remove("account.txt");`  Why 2 different names?

Answer (score 0):

```
the following code
-compiles cleanly
-actually updates the callers' data
-has the appropriate error checking
-properly handles the file open operations
-eliminates the compiler generated calls to memcpy()
     that result from passing the whole struct
     (which C does by value, not as a reference)
     so use a pointer to the struct
     then the compiler will not generate calls to memcpy()

Note: the code really has to perform error checking
      because 'things happen', like wrong permissions,
      and I/O errors, that result in failures


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct client
{
    float curbal;
};

// prototypes
void updateFile( struct client*, float );

// use pointer to x so callers' data gets updated
void updateFile(struct client* x, float bal)
{
    FILE *orig; // input file
    FILE *copy; // output file

    if( NULL == (orig = fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","r")) ) // "r" will start at the beginning of the file
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for account.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( 1 != fread(&x,sizeof(struct client),1,orig) )
    { // then fread failed
        perror( "fread of struct client failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fread successful

    /*fscanf(orig,"%s %s %s %s %f",x.accnum,x.accode,x.fname,x.lname,x.curbal);*/
    x->curbal = bal;

    if( NULL == (copy = fopen("temp.txt","w") ) ) // "w" to write a new file, not append to existing file
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for temp.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( 1 != fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,copy) )
    { // then fwrite failed
        perror( "fwrite of struct client failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fwrite successful

    /*fprintf(copy,"%s %s %s %s %f",x.accnum,x.accode,x.fname,x.lname,x.curbal);*/

    fclose(orig);
    fclose(copy);

    if( 0 != remove("ACCOUNT.txt") ) // this is C, capitalization counts
    { // then, remove failed
        perror( "remove for ACCOUNT.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, remove successful

    if( 0 != rename("temp.txt","ACCOUNT.txt") )
    { // then, rename failed
        perror( "rename from temp.txt to ACCOUNT.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, rename successful

} // end function: updateFile
```

Comment: withdraw will still be the same? When I use the withdraw function after it says success.. it closes.

Comment: I did not give you the (possible) corrections for withdrawal().  in the hope that you would be able to make any corrections, given the example of how to do it in the updateFile() function.  Let me look at the withdrawal() function and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

```
This is the complete code
note that the original code did not compile
for several reasons including 's' is not defined

// clrscr() is documented to be in stdio.h, but my system does not have it there
// so I used system("cls")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct client
{
    char accnum[100];
    char histdate[10];
    char currtime[26];
    float debit;
    float withdrawal;
    float curbal;
    char  lname[30];
    char  fname[30];
};

// prototypes
void updateFile( struct client*);
void withdraw( struct client* );

// use pointer to x so callers' data gets updated
void updateFile(struct client* x)
{
    FILE *orig; // input file
    FILE *copy; // output file

    if( NULL == (orig = fopen("ACCOUNT.txt","r")) ) // "r" will start at the beginning of the file
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for account.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( 1 != fread(&x,sizeof(struct client),1,orig) )
    { // then fread failed
        perror( "fread of struct client failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fread successful

    if( NULL == (copy = fopen("temp.txt","w") ) ) // "w" to write a new file, not append to existing file
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed for temp.txt" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( 1 != fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,copy) )
    { // then fwrite failed
        perror( "fwrite of struct client failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fwrite successful

    /*fprintf(copy,"%s %s %s %s %f",x.accnum,x.accode,x.fname,x.lname,x.curbal);*/

    fclose(orig);
    fclose(copy);

    if( 0 != remove("ACCOUNT.txt") ) // this is C, capitalization counts
    { // then, remove failed
        perror( "remove for ACCOUNT.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, remove successful

    if( 0 != rename("temp.txt","ACCOUNT.txt") )
    { // then, rename failed
        perror( "rename from temp.txt to ACCOUNT.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, rename successful

} // end function: updateFile


// use getchar() which requries #include stdio.h
// getch() is a DOS int24 function
// which requires #include <conio.h>


//void withdraw(struct client x)  // pass parameter as pointer, as previously discussed
void withdraw( struct client* x )
{
    FILE *fp   = NULL;
    //FILE *orig = NULL; // compiler will output warning about unused varible
    //FILE *copy = NULL; // compiler will output warning about unused variable
    //float debit = 0;   // compiler will output warning about unused variable
    float withdrawal = 0.0f;

    if( NULL == (fp = fopen("history.txt","a+") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen history.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful


    printf("====WITHDRAW====\n");
    //printf("Date: %s\n",currdate); // not defined in scope of posted code
    //printf("Time: %s\n",currtime); // not defined in scope of posted code
    printf("Name: %s,%s\n",x->lname,x->fname);
    printf("Account Number: %s\n",x->accnum);
    printf("Current Balance: %.2f\n",x->curbal);

    printf("Withdrawal Amount: Php ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%f",&withdrawal) )
    { // then, scanf failed
        perror( "scanf withdrawal failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    //if((s.curbal-withdrawal) < 0) // 's' not declared
    if((x->curbal-withdrawal) < 0.0f)  // it is a float value so use '0.0f' to compare
    { // then, not enough funds available
        // use one or the other, I suggest using system("cls")
        //clrscr();
        system("cls");
        printf("Transaction Failed.\n\n");
        printf("Insufficient Funds!!!\n\n");
    }

    else
    { // else, enough funds available
        x->curbal -= withdrawal;
        //clrscr();
        system("cls");
        updateFile(x);

        fprintf( fp,"%s %s %s %.2f %.2f\n",
            x->accnum,
            x->histdate,
            x->currtime,
            x->debit,
            x->withdrawal );

        printf("Transaction Completed.\n\n");
        printf("Php %.2f was deducted.\n\n",withdrawal);
        printf("Remaining Balance: Php %.2f\n\n\n",x->curbal);
    } // end if

    fclose( fp ); // cleanup

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I noticed that 'ACCOUNT' was capitalized in some places in the posted code and lower case in others.  the capitalization needs to be the same as the actual file name